# Parse LocalDateTime in TestRestTemplate not working (Bad request )

Tags: spring, spring-boot

A newbie to Spring boot running integration testing. Using exchange method of `TestRestTemplate` I am unable to pass LocalDateTime request params to test method. Here's my `MemberController` method and `MemberControllerTest` method. I guess it has to do with the date and format because the same exchange method works when I test for get member with id as integer.

```
    @Test
        @Transactional
        public void getTopMembersss() throws Exception {

            LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.JULY, 29, 19, 30, 40);
            LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 01, 19, 30, 40);

            ResponseEntity<List<TopMemberDTO>> response = template.exchange(
                    "/api/member/top-member?startTime={startTime}&endTime={endTime}", HttpMethod.GET, null,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<TopMemberDTO>>() {
                    }, startTime.toString(), endTime.toString());

            // , "2018-12-31T12:12:12", "2018-12-31T12:12:12"

            Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());

        }

@GetMapping(path = "/api/member/top-member?startTime={startTime}&endTime={endTime}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<TopMemberDTO>> getTopMembers(
            @RequestParam(value = "startTime", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime startTime,
            @RequestParam(value = "endTime", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime endTime) {
        List<TopMemberDTO> topDrivers = new ArrayList<>();
        /**
         * Your Implementation Here.
         * 
         */

        topDrivers = memberService.findTopMembersCount(startTime, endTime);

        if (topDrivers.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(topDrivers);

    }

}


java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200> but was:<400>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
    at com.thankgod.controller.MemberControllerTest.getTopMembersss(MemberControllerTest.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/member/top-member?startTime={startTime}&endTime={endTime}")
```

to

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/member/top-member")
```

Comment: Wow, it worked like a charm. So the request param didn't need to be in the URL of the spring controller method. Thank you.

Comment: yes, only the path the method should handle, and then you can control request parameters using @RequestParam(value="name",required=ture|false(if it's optional))